# Как с с помощью обработчика события OnBeforeEventAdd админу прикрепить вложение письма ,а покупателю нет?

Tags: битрикс

как сделать такое в компоненте mein fitbeck? письма отличаются вложением
нужно избавится от id почтовых шаблонов
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не совсем понимаю. Если у вас всегда одно и тоже вложение, то 2 почтовых шаблона как раз идеально решают ситуацию. И да в качестве обработчика лучше использовать `OnBeforeSend`

Comment: Да ,но не хочу привязываться к их id  а сделать проверку если админ, то с вложением ,а если нет то без, так как могут удалить шаблон и id поменяется